# Access the SD card files from Android application

Tags: android

I have the following requirements:

1. When the user clicks on the button , the SD card should be accessible to the user.
2. The user clicks on a specific image & I need to save the SD card path of the image selected
3. I need to resize the image before displaying that to the user within the Android application

Kindly provide me any blog/article link from where I can get the sample code for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this for image resize: http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard file APIs to access "/sdcard", or more safely:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Also, you can scale images easily using

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()
```