# read a file from sd card in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the SD card files from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721775/access-the-sd-card-files-from-android-application)

I am developing an android application which involves reading a file placed in sd card of android.Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this javadoc documenting the [Environment class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You should also read the data storage section: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html