# Update: Soundboard Application Source Code

Tags: android, eclipse, sd-card, ringtone

OK I got it to work. This will save the file as a ringtone, notification, or alarm based on     the context menu. (Only ringtone function is shown due to space conservation)

Need help with:

For some reason no sound plays after awhile.(about 20 or so presses and won't play again until you back out of the app and launch it again) Also I've been told "/sdcard/media/etc" isn't "the correct way" to do it.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to

1.release/pause/stop the sound from playing when the home button is pressed, a text is recieved, or the back button is pressed to exit the app, etc

and

2.the correct way to get the sdcard. I'd appreciate it.

```
MediaPlayer mp1;
MediaPlayer mp2;
MediaPlayer mp3;
MediaPlayer mp4;
MediaPlayer mp5;


protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if(mp1 != null){
    mp1.release();
}
if(mp2 != null){
mp2.release();
}
if(mp3 != null){
    mp3.release();
}
if(mp4 != null){
mp4.release();
}
if(mp5 != null){
    mp5.release();
}
}

protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if(mp1 != null){
    mp1.stop();
}
if(mp2 != null){
mp2.stop();
}
if(mp3 != null){
    mp3.stop();
}
if(mp4 != null){
mp4.stop();
}
if(mp5 != null){
    mp5.stop();
}
}
}

protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Don't use hard-coded values, but use variables instead. Create a variable that keeps track of which button is pushed and pass that variable along to the method for saving the sound.

Comment: //Button One /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Button SoundButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound1);
registerForContextMenu(SoundButton1);
j = "Sound1";
SoundButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
mCurrentSound = R.raw.sound1;
mSoundManager.playSound(0); 
}
}); 

//Button Two /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
registerForContextMenu(SoundButton2);
j = "Sound2";
SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
mCurrentSound = R.raw.sound2;
mSoundManager.playSound(1); 

and the ringtone function to this

Comment: public void funcRingtone(int id){ 
if 
(saveRing(mCurrentSound)) //Need to get this to change based on what button is pressed!!!
{ 
// Code if successful 
Toast.makeText(this, j+" Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 

and that seems to work. The only problem now is since mCurrentSound is set to R.raw.sound2 at the bottom the Ringtone function is also set to R.raw.sound2. Same with int j on button 5. Since it's the last button the sound name is always Sound5 so no matter what button you save it always says Sound5 was saved as Ringtone.

Comment: I changed the code to that ^^ but now the sound that is saved is the last one played. mCurrentSound = R.raw.soundWhatever but the last one is sound5 so sound5 is ALWAYS saved. I'm not sure why. It's like the button OnClickListener { stuff that goes here } doesn't matter. It always ends up taking the last variable that was set and using it .

Comment: You'd better edit your question and add your changes there. It is quite hard to read it spread over several comments.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. The code has been updated to reflect what I've learned so far. Thanks again for any help you can provide @THelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1: Add a `onPause` method to your activity and call [MediaPlayer's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) `stop()` method. You should also add a `onDestroy` method and call `release` to free the resources used by the mediaplayer.

Answer to Q2: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721775/access-the-sd-card-files-from-android-application). For more details read the Android Developers info on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: Thanks again THelper I'll implement your suggestions soon. Thanks for not treating me like a noob.

Comment: The Android Gods must be smiling tonight. I could have sworn I tried 
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/media/audio/ringtones/";

before and it threw an error. Maybe in my late night coding i missed a punctuation or something. onPause and onDrestroy were also exactly what I needed. Your answer will be marked correctly and if there's anything else I can do (not code wise, obviously lol) let me know.

Comment: Well I spoke too soon. When I try just mp2.stop() on onPause it works but there are 10 total media players and something goes wrong when i do mp1.stop() to mp10.stop() do I need an if(mp1.isplaying()){mp1.stop()} else if mp2 is playing stop etc? The saving still works.

Comment: To quote the [Mediaplayer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) "Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state." You should not call stop if the mediaplayer is in any other state.

Comment: But didn't you tell me to do stop() on the onPause? i tried an if/else chain to see what player is playing mp1 through mp10 and i still get a force close if you press back or home. or do i need to do the if/else in the onPause and add an if/else to the buttons. like if mp1 is playing stop it then if it's stopped prepare and then play it.

Comment: I think you are confusing the state of your activity with the state of a mediaplayer. When your app goes to the background it will start the onPause method and possibly also the onDestroy. It's best to always check the state of your mediaplayers before doing an action (unless you know for sure what their state is.)

Comment: OK I realize the difference but were you meaning if another button is pushed I should pause and release the original sound or did you mean when the activity is paused I should pause the sound?

Comment: Your question (1.) was how to pause the mediaplayer when the app goes to the background and I merely provided an answer for this (call stop() in onPause()). If you want the mediaplayers to stop playing in other situations then that's totally up to you.

Comment: Yes you're correct. It does stop and that's what I wanted it to do. However, it only works IF the button has been pushed. For example if I do mp2.stop (in the onPause) but never actually push button 2. Whenever I hit the home or back button the app force closes.

Comment: Never mind I got it. Made it so IF the player ISN'T null release or pause. w00t :)

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the onPause onDestroy methods. Time for me to go to bed. If you'd like to try the app out and give me some other suggestions download it from my DropBox here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675342/SteampunkSoundboard.apk I really do appreciate your help.